# How to install a translation ".po" in django app?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, django-lfs

I finished a few days ago, creating a translation file for Django-LFS (Lightning Fast Shop) for my native language (pt_BR). Now that it's done, I need to install the ".po" file that I downloaded after finishing my translation in Transifex.

Ok, I downloaded the file, but now that I need to install it, I just can't figure how. I tried putting the file in 'lfs-installer' folder, using "bin/django compilemessages -a", tried the same thing but with the file in many different folders, but I just can't make my LFS use my translation file...

Does anyone know how to make a translation package work on lfs? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

put you .po file in the path:

```
<your_django_project>/conf/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/
```

and run
django-admin makemessages -a

Comment: didn't work... after doing that I restarted the server, but all the strings were still in english...

Comment: check LANGUAGE_CODE option in settings.py is not "en-en"

Answer (score 0):

If you do not already have one, create a folder called Locale. Then in your settings.py folder you must tell it where to find the locale paths. Something like this:

```
LOCALE_PATHS{
C:/sdalfjasd/dfalsdjkf/locale
}
```

Also make sure you have locale middleware in your middleware...

You can probably effectively track down that syntax and specifics, now that I pointed you in the right direction.

Once you have those things set up, you can run your `makemessage -a` command, which will create a folder in your locale folder for the -a you put in. Then you can browse to this, inside it there should be a .po file (there might not be). If there is not, just put your .po file you made in there.

Then browse to your project in your CMD, and run `compilemessages -a`. This should compile your .po files into .mo files, the files necessary for translations to work.

Hopefully I did not go crazy off-track...

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work using the following settings:

```
import os
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('pt-br', u"Português"),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    DIRNAME + '/locale',
]
```

Than create a `locale` folder aside of the settings.py folder and follow Django official instructions. The desired path for your `django.po` file is: `locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`. After that, use `compilemessages` tool and restart the server.

It should work.

**Tip:** django-lfs uses `locale` module to handle currency display, but there is a bug for locale module that makes it to show `1234,00 R$` instead of `R$ 1234,00`. If it bites you, put the following into your `settings.py`:

```
# Fix for LC_MONETARY bug: http://www.sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1294
import locale
locale._override_localeconv.update({'p_cs_precedes': 1, 'n_cs_precedes': 1})
```

Good luck.